# Django dev server slowness with chrome + other instance / browser

Tags: django, google-chrome

First let me say that this is not about production settings for django - it's for local development and testing.

I'm testing out multiple user scenarios, requiring I log in as several different users. I'm logged in as user A using Chrome, and user B using Chrome's incognito mode, and as user C using Firefox. I'm using "manage.py runserver" to run the dev server.

The first instance with regular Chrome (user A) works well and is fast. The other instances are very slow - perhaps better described as stuck. They sit around doing nothing for 10-30 seconds, and then finally display the page fairly quickly.

While the other browsers are stuck I can go to the first one (user A) and click around and it works well and is fast. In other words only the requests from the other two instances get stuck - the first instance always works well.

The resource that's slow appears to be the html page, not the static content.

The backend is Django 1.1.1 with SQLite as the database running on OS X 1.6.7 .

Any ideas? Is Chrome doing something special to hog the connection?

Comment: You should check if the statics are loading very late for the browser to render, or something.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with projects hosted on my machine(not only Django) + Chrome. The only solution for me so far is to kill the server with C-c and start it again.

Comment: Good idea Lakshman. I checked via Chrome's dev console and it's the html page that takes a long time - the static files download quite quickly as soon as the html is available.

Comment: @Parand is the same behaviour happening if you only try one browser at a time?

Comment: James, do you mean if I only have one browser open (ie. one user logged in)? When it's only one browser everything is nice and fast. If you mean will the same slowness show up if I only use browsers B (or C) without using the others, yes, the slowness will be still be there. In other words the issue is not that there are multiple simultaneous requests - the slowness will be there even if a single browser is making a request at any point in time.

Comment: After having experienced this a number of times - webkit browsers seems to make the devserver hang - and as Django isn't multi-threaded nothing works.I found the most convenient way to fix this is using [django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver). It seems to solve that problem (at least for me) as well as adding some useful functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a known issue "Development web server sometimes hangs with Chrome":

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16099

It is fixed recenty in django trunk:

https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16427

Comment: Looks like that might be it, although I'm not on trunk so I can't try easily.